# Trying to open an app in the Play Store (android)

Tags: nativescript

I'm trying to direct the user to the play store.

```html
import app = require("application");

var intent = new android.content.Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW" );

intent.setData( "market://details?id=MY.APP.LINK" );

app.android.currentContext.startActivity(intent);
```

The above isn't working!

I think the problem has to do with my translation from Java code to something {N} can use.

Comment: I did a PR to nic raboys ratings plugin with code for this. Check there for the snippet. On phone or I'd do it :)

Comment: Brad meant this one: https://github.com/nraboy/nativescript-ratings/pull/1/files

Comment: Genius! Haven't tried it - but no doubt it'll work. If you bump your response to ANSWER - I'll tag it as such.

Comment: Hey dashman, you can also post as an answer a working solution to this interesting case so the community would have easy access to it. Me personally would find that very useful!

Answer (score 0):

@Brad Martin gave the answer in comments but I'm adding this for readability, as I needed this snippet. Didn't try the iOS part yet.

Here is the code I used, with TypeScript.

#### First, add those lines in import

```
import * as application from "application";
import * as Utility from "utils/utils";
declare var android: any;
```

#### Then, you can use a function like this one for Android

```
gotoPlayStore() {
    let androidPackageName = application.android.packageName;
    let uri = android.net.Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + androidPackageName);
    let myAppLinkToMarket = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    // Launch the PlayStore
    application.android.foregroundActivity.startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
}
```

#### You can use this code for iOS devices

```
gotoAppStore() {
    let appStore = "";
    appStore = "itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/en/app/id" + myAppId;
    Utility.openUrl(appStore);
}
```

> This code is based on the plugin `nativescript-rating` from Nic Raboy and this particular file : https://github.com/nraboy/nativescript-ratings/blob/master/ratings.ts
>
> You may get this error on Android : **ERROR Error: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=your.package.id }** , but it's working on real device, as Play Store application is running on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

```html
            try
            {
                let uri = android.net.Uri.parse( "market://details?id=com.company" );

                var intent = new android.content.Intent( android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri );

                application.android.foregroundActivity.startActivity( intent );
            }
            catch ( e2 )
            {
                console.error( "Error =" + e2.message + "=" );
            }
```